# How to add command line arguments when building jar with Maven

Tags: java, maven

I can add a command line argument when running a .jar from the command line by running:

```
java --my-command-line-argument argumentValue -jar myJarFile.jar
```

I am using `mvn clean package` to build this .jar in the first place, is there a configuration value I can change in the pom.xml so that this argument will be added when I just run `java -jar myJarFile.jar`?
I tried adding a property in the pom.xml with:

```
<properties>
  <my-command-line-argument>argumentValue</my-command-line-argument>
<properties>
```

Additionally, this argument is only required when using Java 9 (It's called `Add-Exports`).
And I also tried adding:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>name</id>               
            <configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
                <source>9</source>
                <target>9</target>
                <compilerArgs>
                    <arg>--my-command-line-argument</arg>
                    <arg>argumentValue</arg>
                </compilerArgs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>           
</plugin>
```

Which compiles, but doesn't have the desired effect.

Comment: If you use JDK 9 you have to have a `module-info.java` file which contains the exports...

Comment: Do you want to build jar and then execute java -jar for this jar during the same Maven build?

Comment: @Ivan no not the same build, separate commands, I'll clarify my question

Comment: @khmarbaise so for `Add-Exports` would it be like: `module java.base { exports jdk.internal.ref; }`? I realise this doesn't build when compiled with Java < 9 too, ideally I'd want a solution which could be built against both

Comment: Simply `module-info.java` must be compiled with Java 9 there is no other solution. Best would be to build with JDK 9 and define target class for JDK 8...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#commandlineargfile

The ideal/official solution is to use an @args file that you can port or distribute with your jar.

Create a file with your arguments @argFile
call

```
java/c @argFile something.jar
```

the file argFile (no extension) would contain whatever, such as

```
--patch-module java.transaction=~/.m2\repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.3/javax.transaction-api-1.3.jar --patch-module java.xml.bind=~/.m2\repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.0/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar
```

you can also create a classes file if you really need to.
IntelliJ & Netbeans supports this out the box.

Try to place all of your exports/uses/provides/opens etc in your module-info.java instead of using command lines.

Keep the command line arguments purely to what can only be defined on the command line. patch-module add-module etc, something like "Add-Exports" should most definitely  be defined in your module-info.java class.